# Contar quantidade de LI dentro de uma UL

Tags: jquery

Mostrar quantidade de LI dentro de uma UL.

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<ul class="rodapeUlCat margin-top-25">
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rodapeCat">Outras Categorias (16)</div>
```

O que eu quero fazer, é onde diz **Outras Categorias (16)** em "16", ele mostre a quantidade de `li` que consta dentro da `ul`.

Fiz um Jquery:

```
$( ".rodapeUlCat" ).append( $( "<li>" ) );
var n = $( "li" ).length;
$( ".rodapeCat" ).text( + n + );
```

Gostaria de saber o que eu fiz errado. O `length` conta os elementos, certo? Talvez o erro seja o `append`, mas não sei o que colocar no lugar.

Comment: Você ão precisa colocar o `+` para escrever um texto não concatenado

Comment: O erro é o `+ n +`, isso é um erro de sintaxe e deve estar sendo mostrado no console do browser. Use `.text(n)`, ou `.text('Categorias(' + n + ')')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro, um cuidado:

Em vez de `$( "li" ).length` use `$( ".rodapeUlCat li" ).length`, para contar os `<li>` apenas da div desejada.

Talvez seja o caso inclusive de você usar um `id` separado em cada bloco caso tenha vários pela tela, ou localizar o elemento mais próximo via JQuery antes de fazer a contagem.

Desta forma, o código fica assim:

```
var n = $( ".rodapeUlCat li" ).length;
$( ".rodapeCat" ).text( "Outras categorias( " + n + " )" );
```

Fiz um **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/8zy6kseL/)** que gera aleatoriamente a quantidade de `<li>`s para demonstrar melhor.

Comment: Eu não posso usar ID, pois isso será gerenciável, e aí o ID vai repetir.

Comment: Lembre-se de que você pode usar classes, e gerar um ID sequencial. O fato de ter classe não impede um ID apenas como auxiliar (você continuaria fazendo como está hoje, mas poria um ID sequencial ao gerar a página).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `.size()` para fazer esta ação.

```
var total = $(".rodapeUlCat li").size();
$(".rodapeCat").text(total);
```

Veja o [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rk88uge5/)

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguma forma de realizar a contagem apenas de divs visiveis utilizando o código acima?

por exemplo no código abaixo:

```js
var total = $(".rodapeUlCat li").size();
    $(".rodapeCat").text(total);
```

```css
.esconde{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="rodapeUlCat margin-top-25">
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
        <li class="esconde><h3><a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rodapeCat">Outras Categorias (16)</div>
```